# Firebase permission for writing data in second table befor checking data in first table

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase. I am following [this Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtoxRg-kbt0) and trying to validate data, but didn't know why my data is not validating. I want to check first **Authors** table that user exists or not if exists then he can able to write.

**Simulation results**

```
Type  write
Location  /posts/1/1
Data  { "Authors": { "1": true } }
Auth  { "provider": "google", "uid": "1" }
Admin false
```

**Write denied**

```
Line 69 (/posts/1/1)
validate: "root.child('Authors').child(newData.child('Authors').val()).exists()"
```

**My security rules are:**

```
"users": {
  "$UID": {
    ".read": "auth.uid == $UID",
    ".write": "auth.uid == $UID"
  }
},
"Authors": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": false
},
"posts": {
  ".read": true,
  "$POSTID": {
    ".write": "auth.uid != null",
    "$UID": {
      ".validate": "root.child('Authors').child(newData.child('Authors').val()).exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the data that's being written to `/posts/1/1`:

```
{
  "Authors": {
    "1": true
  }
}
```

The validation rule is extracting the following data for the expression `newData.child('Authors').val()`:

```
{
  "1": true
}
```

That's an object - not a string - so it's not a sensible value to pass to `root.child('Authors').child(...)` and that's why the validation rule fails.

It seems a little strange to have a structure that supports multiple authors, but if that's what you really want, you could put an additional validation rule deeper into the hierarchy:

```
"posts": {
  ".read": true,
  "$POSTID": {
    ".write": "auth.uid != null",
    "$UID": {
      ".validate": "root.child('users').child($UID).val()).exists()",
      "Authors": {
        "$AUTHORID": {
          ".validate": "root.child('Authors').child($AUTHORID).val()).exists()",
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

These rules would ensure that there is `/users` entry for `$UID` and an `/authors` entry for `$AUTHORID`. That might not be what you want, but, hopefully, it will make things it a little clearer regarding the rules themselves.

Comment: I've changed these lines

**".write": "auth.uid != null",
    "$UID": {
      ".validate": "root.child('Authors').child(newData.child('Authors').val()).exists()"
    }**
with this line

**".write": "root.child('Authors').child(auth.uid).exists()"**

and now it is working perfect.